# How to export lm summary to data frame using broom after modifying object with lm.beta?

Tags: r, dataframe

I did regression analysis and then standardized it by using `lm.beta::lm.beta()`This way, it adds a column called Standardized to the result, which looks like below:

```
  lmfit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
  lmfit2 <- lm.beta::lm.beta(lmfit)
  summary(lmfit2)
            Estimate   Standardized Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 40.82854   0.0000000    2.75747     14.807   1.76e-14    
cyl         -1.29332   -0.38324     0.65588     -1.972   0.058947
...
```

I want to convert it to dataframe so I can save it to Excel. I used `tidy` from `library(broom)` But it messed up with the headers.

```
term        estimate   std.error    statistic   p.value  
(Intercept) 40.82854   0.0000000    2.75747     14.807   1.76e-14    
SP500TR     -1.29332   -0.38324     0.65588     -1.972   0.058947
...
```

As you can see, the std.error column is actually Standardized etc. How to fix the headers? Many thanks!

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I think their question is what to do, since **broom** specifically doesn't handle this case.

Comment: If you type `broom:::tidy.lm` you'll see that the code is quite straightforward. If you modify it to add the missing column name to the `nn` variable and prefix all the **broom** functions with `broom:::` just to be safe it should work fine. @DavidRobinson might be even be interested in a pull request to handle these...

Comment: One should assume user error until proven otherwise.

Comment: I updated my example. I get `tidy` returns one row for each coefficient with five columns. My problem is that I had an extra column (Standardized) and I wanted to convert all six columns into dataframe so that I can save the results to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I described in my comment:

```
tidy.lm.beta <- function (x, conf.int = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, exponentiate = FALSE, 
                                 quick = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (quick) {
        co <- stats::coef(x)
        ret <- data.frame(term = names(co), estimate = unname(co))
        return(broom:::process_lm(ret, x, conf.int = FALSE, exponentiate = exponentiate))
    }
    co <- stats::coef(summary(x))
    nn <- c("estimate","std.estimate", "std.error", "statistic", "p.value")
    if (inherits(co, "listof")) {
        ret <- plyr::ldply(co, broom:::fix_data_frame, nn[1:ncol(co[[1]])], 
                                             .id = "response")
        ret$response <- stringr::str_replace(ret$response, "Response ", 
                                                                                 "")
    }
    else {
        ret <- broom:::fix_data_frame(co, nn[1:ncol(co)])
    }
    broom:::process_lm(ret, x, conf.int = conf.int, conf.level = conf.level, 
                         exponentiate = exponentiate)
}

lmfit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
lmfit2 <- lm.beta::lm.beta(lmfit)
```

And then:

```
> tidy.lm.beta(lmfit2)
         term    estimate std.estimate  std.error  statistic      p.value
1 (Intercept) 40.82853674    0.0000000 2.75746793 14.8065319 1.761402e-14
2         cyl -1.29331972   -0.3832400 0.65587675 -1.9718944 5.894681e-02
3        disp  0.01159924    0.2385278 0.01172681  0.9891215 3.313856e-01
4          hp -0.02053838   -0.2336456 0.01214677 -1.6908508 1.023791e-01
5          wt -3.85390352   -0.6256700 1.01547364 -3.7951783 7.589470e-04
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. It looks complicated to me as I'm very new to R. What I end up doing was assigning names to the columns `colnames`.